# How to add ajax form fields to POST in parent page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Apologies for posting but I have googled and searched this site ad infinitum and can't find the answer - very possibly I am asking the wrong question but here goes.

I have a page that makes an ajax call when the value of a select box is changed.  Basically it searches a database for values which correspond to the selection and then generates a series of radio buttons with a description.  I am using this to set some user preferences by user type, and what I want to happen is that these fields sit within a larger form on the parent page and are posted to the database when the parent form is submitted.

However, I can't work out how to make the fields generated by the ajax part of the form.  They are just pulling into an (otherwise hidden) div which is empty until populated by ajax.  I have a feeling that I should perhaps be doing something with dummy fields in the parent form but I can't figure out what.  Basically how do I make those fields that are generated by a separate page part of the form within the page that calls it?

Thank you and sorry, I'm sure this is basic stuff but it's driving me nuts...

James

Sorry folks, here are the requested code excerpts...

```
<!--Start Ajax for pulling permission options through-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
        // when any option from aspects list is selected
        jQuery("select[name='group']").change(function(){           

            var optionValue = jQuery("select[name='group']").val(); //passes proposed user group as selected from combobox  
            var userType =    "<?php echo $usertype ?>";  //passes current user's user group


            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "viaajax/pullpermissions.php",
                data: "usergroup="+optionValue+"&usertype="+userType,
                beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#ajaxLoader").show(); jQuery("#PermissionsAjax").hide();},
                complete: function(){ jQuery("#ajaxLoader").hide(); },
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#PermissionsAjax").html(response);
                    jQuery("#PermissionsAjax").show();

                }
            });          
        });
    });
</script>
```

Parent form:

```
<form action="approval.php" form id="formID" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <table>
        <tr><td valign="top"><input type="text" class="validate[required, custom[email]] text-input"  name="email1" id="email1" placeholder="Email address (required)" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $recordemail;?>" disabled/></td><td width=6></td></tr>

        <tr height="8"></tr>

        <tr><td valign="top"><input type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" data-errormessage-value-missing="You must enter a first name" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"  placeholder="First name (required)" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>" /></td><td width=6></td><td valign="top"><input type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" data-errormessage-value-missing="You must enter a last name" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name (required)" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>" /></td></tr>

        <tr height="8"></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="House number and street" size="25" maxlength="50"  value="<?php echo $address1;?>"/></td></tr>  

        <tr height="1"></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Town" size="25" maxlength="50"  value="<?php echo $address2;?>"/></td></tr>

        <tr height="1"></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="address3" placeholder="County" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $address3;?>" /></td></tr>

        <tr height="1"></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="userpostcode" id="userpostcode" class="validate[required] text-input" data-errormessage-value-missing="You must enter a postcode"  placeholder="Postcode (required)" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $postcode;?>" /></td></tr>

        <tr height="8"></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="numeric" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile number" size="25" maxlength="50"  value="<?php echo $phone;?>"/></td></tr>

        </table>
```

```
<div id="thirdcolumnR">
<div id="subwindowtitlebar">User group and permissions</div>
<div id ="subcontent">



        <?php if ($usertype<99) { //This requires that approving user has sysadmin rights 99 in order to grant sysdamin rights and then also restricts users to being able to grant access at or below their own level only

        $query="SELECT SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key, SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.group_name FROM SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS WHERE SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key<=$usertype ORDER BY SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key";  

        } else {

        $query="SELECT SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key, SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.group_name FROM SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS WHERE SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key ORDER BY SYSTEM_USER_GROUPS.Key"; 

        }

$result=mysql_query($query); 

echo "<SELECT id=\"group\" name=\"group\" data-size=\"6\"><OPTION value=\"\">Select a user group...</option>";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) { 

if ($row[0] == $user_type) {  

    echo "<OPTION value=$row[0] selected>$row[1]</option>"; 

} else { 

    echo "<OPTION value=$row[0] >$row[1]</option>";}

}

echo "</SELECT>"; ?>


<?php  
        echo "<div id=\"ajaxLoader\" style=\"display:none\"><img src=\"images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"loading...\" align=\"center\"></div>";
        echo "<div id=\"PermissionsAjax\" style=\"display:none\">";



        echo "</div>"; //closes PermissionsAjax

?>





</div><!--closes subcontent-->    

<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="greenbutton" value="Confirm" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
<?php // Store the required hidden values.
echo '<input type="hidden" name="activate" value="' . $id . '" />';
?>
```

Form called via ajax:

```
<?php
$usergroup = $_GET['usergroup']; //selected group for approval
$usertype = $_GET['usertype'];  //actual group of approver logged in


if(!$usergroup) {
    return false;
}


require_once ('../mysql_connect.php'); 

if ($usertype<99) { //This requires that only sysadmin can see and assign permissions over the 'minimum permission' level specified

            $querypermissions="SELECT SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.key, SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.permission, SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.minimum_user_group FROM SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS WHERE $usergroup>=SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.minimum_user_group ORDER BY SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.sort_order";   

            $issysadmin="";

            } else {

            echo "<br /><br /><div id=\"boxit\"><table><tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"images/exclam.png\"></td><td width=\"10px\"></td><td valign=\"top\">You have System Administrator rights and can assign any user group or privilege.</td></tr></table></div><br />";

            $querypermissions="SELECT SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.key, SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.permission, SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.minimum_user_group FROM SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS ORDER BY SYSTEM_SECURITY_PERMISSION_LEVELS.sort_order"; 

            $issysadmin="<br /><br /><br /><div id=\"boxit\"><table><tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"images/exclam.png\"></td><td width=\"10px\"></td><td valign=\"top\"><b><font color=\"red\">Permissions shown in red aren't usually available to this user group.  Proceed with caution if granting an Administrator's exception.</font></b></td></tr></table></div>";

            }
            $resultpermissions=mysql_query($querypermissions); 


                echo "<table><tr height=\"20px\"></tr>";
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultpermissions, MYSQL_NUM)) { 



                        if ($row[2] <= $usergroup) {
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"80px\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"switch-toggle switch-candy switch-candy-blue\">
    <input id=\"1radio$row[0]\" name=\"permission$row[0]\" type=\"radio\" value=\"1\">
    <label for=\"1radio$row[0]\" onclick=\"\">On</label>

    <input id=\"2radio$row[0]\" name=\"permission$row[0]\" type=\"radio\" value=\"0\" checked>
    <label for=\"2radio$row[0]\" onclick=\"\">Off</label><a></a></div>
</td><td width=\"20\"></td><td>";
                    echo "<font color=\"black\">permission".$row[0]."&nbsp;".$row[1]."</font>";
                echo "</td></tr><tr height=\"10px\"></tr>";

                    } else { 

                echo "<tr><td width=\"80px\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"switch-toggle switch-candy switch-candy-blue\">
    <input id=\"1radio$row[0]\" name=\"permission$row[0]\" type=\"radio\" value=\"1\">
    <label for=\"1radio$row[0]\" onclick=\"\">On</label>

    <input id=\"2radio$row[0]\" name=\"permission$row[0]\" type=\"radio\" value=\"0\" checked>
    <label for=\"2radio$row[0]\" onclick=\"\">Off</label><a></a></div>
</td><td width=\"20\"></td><td>";
                    echo "<font color=\"red\">permission".$row[0]."&nbsp;".$row[1]."</font>";
                echo "</td></tr><tr height=\"10px\"></tr>";


                }

            }

            echo "</table>"; //closes PermissionsAjax
            echo $issysadmin;



?>
```

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions here it really helps to see your code, so we can help you move forward.

Comment: It's always best to narrow your question down into specifics as much as possible

Comment: It'd be best to post your ajax call, form and resposnse to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you can just construct form fields and append them to the form. If the form doesn't exist yet, you can append the form itself to a random div if you'd like. Nothing fancy about that actually :) When you've added form fields 'on the fly', and post the form, the form fields will be posted as if they would've existed on loading the page.

To add a form field to a form, just do something like this (warning: jQuery ahead!)

```
$('<input/>')
    .attr('type', 'text')
    .attr('name', 'my-generated-form-field')
    .appendTo('form');
```

Check out the [fiddle over here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljp2C/) for an example. The form fields are created without the use of ajax, but where the data comes from on which you base, for example, the field names, doesn't really matter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just make the whole html in the ajax, and just echo it to the js file:

**AJAX:**

```
$s = '';
$s .= 'your form html stuff here';

echo $s;
```

**JS:**

```
$('#dummy_div').html(data);
```

You would have to put a dummy div somewhere into the template/html file with this solution though.